# gutenberg block - how to force update after attribute changed?

Tags: block-editor

I built a custom Gutenberg block to show ONE post of a custom post type called `story`. Most things are finally working fine, story shows up as wanted via ServerSideRendering. To select the story-to-show there is a List of radio buttons in the sidebar.

What I want: 
 - after choosing a story from the radio buttons, I want the shown story to refresh.
From some examples I believe this gets solved with `withSelect` or `useSelect` or something like that. But I can't wrap my head around it, I don't understand how to use them for my case.

When the `story_id` of the edit function gets updated, the Story object needs to get rendered again with that new `story_id`.

Here's the code:

```
/**
* Story-Block: osf-blocks-story
*
* Gives back a rendered story (list of images with text & title) after selecting from the left block sidebar
*
* based on create-guten-block
*/

import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { ServerSideRender, RadioControl, PanelBody } from '@wordpress/components';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Component, Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect, withSelect } from '@wordpress/data';


let $ = jQuery;

// short for console.log
function cl(words) { console.log('drx-osf-story, block.js: ' + words); }

// to get more object infos than console.log(obj + 'some comment');
function ol(object, words='') {
   cl(words + ': \\/');
   console.log(object);
}

// Represents a single story, i.e. a collection of parts with image, short text and possibly a title
class Story extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           story_id: props.story_id
       }
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <ServerSideRender
               block="osf-blocks/story"
               attributes={this.state}
           />
       )
   }
}

// Represents a list of radiobuttons to select one of all stories
class StoriesListControl extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           changeHandler: props.changeHandler,
           story_id: props.story_id,
           options: props.options
       };
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <InspectorControls>
               <PanelBody title='Story auswählen:'>
                   <RadioControl
                       label="Wähle, welche Story hier eingefügt werden soll."
                       help="Die Story muss vorher über das Story-Interface angelegt worden sein."
                       selected={ this.state.story_id }
                       options={ this.state.options }
                       onChange={ this.state.changeHandler }
                   />
               </PanelBody>
           </InspectorControls>
       );
   }
};


// Registering the block
registerBlockType('osf-blocks/story', {

   title: 'Story' ,
   icon: 'images-alt2',
   category: 'widgets',
   attributes: {
       story_id: {
           type: 'string'
       }
   },
   keywords: [
       'osf-blocks-story',
       'Story',
       'Stories'
   ],


   edit: (props) => {

       // what to do with withSelect/useSelect here??

       const {
           attributes: { story_id },
           setAttributes
           } = props;

       // called, if a radiobutton gets selected
       const changeHandler = (new_story_id) => {
           setAttributes({ story_id: new_story_id });
       };

       // fetching the list of all stories (custom post type) from server
       const getStoriesList = () => {
           let answer;
           $.ajax({
               url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                   action: 'stories_list'
               },
               async: false,
               timeout: 3000 // ms
           }).done((rspns) => {
               // removing trailing 0  - what does it mean?
               answer = { status: 'success', result: JSON.parse(rspns.substr(0, rspns.length - 1)) };
           }).fail((xhr, status) => {
               cl('request failed: ' + status);
               ol(xhr);
               answer = { status:'fail',  log: status }
           });
           return answer;
       };

       // tie it all together
       let response = getStoriesList();
       let output;

       if ( 'success' == response.status) {
       // AJAX for storieslist succeeded

           ol(response, 'response');

           output = (
               <Fragment>
                   <StoriesListControl
                       changeHandler={ changeHandler }
                       story_id={ story_id }
                       options={ response.result }
                   />
                   <div className="story-container">
                       <div id={ "story" + story_id } className="story-preview container">
                           <Story story_id={ story_id } />
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </Fragment>
           );

       }
       else if ('fail' == response.status) {
       // AJAX failed
           output = (
               <Fragment>
                   <div className="story-container">
                       <p>No connection to the server: { response.log }</p>
                   </div>
               </Fragment>
           );
       }

       return output;
   },

   save: (props) => {
       return null;
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, you are treating the asynchronous jQuery AJAX call as a synchronous function, resulting in `getStoriesList()` consistently returning `undefined` as the function returns immediately after dispatching the HTTP request; trying to access `response.status` should be consistently throwing `ReferenceError: response is not defined`.

In almost all cases it is more ideal to access data through the selectors provided on Gutenberg's various data-stores - many selectors will asynchronously acquire data from the REST API if it is missing or uninitialized in the store, then update the respective state, and automatically trigger updates for every component which has subscribed to changes to that state using `withSelect()` or `useSelect()`.

In circumventing Gutenberg's data-flow here, you are unable to update the component when new data comes in using `useSelect()` or `withSelect()` because the response from your AJAX handler does not trigger a state update in the stores, and thus the stores will not notify any subscribed functions or components. The current implementation also results in an HTTP request being dispatched every time the component is rendered, which is unecessary.

In this case, the `getStoriesList()` function and associated AJAX handler returning a list of CPT posts should be succinctly replaced with the `getEntityRecords()` selector on the `core` data store. We can get access to the core data store's selectors via the object returned by `select( 'core' )`. Wrapping that access up in a `useSelect()` hook creates a subscription to the core store, re-rendering `edit()` automatically whenever the data being selected changes in state.

Further, the second argument of `useSelect()` is an array of dependencies. By adding `story_id` to it, we can cache the post list and only retrieve a new one when `story_id` changes.

```
// Registering the block
registerBlockType('osf-blocks/story', {
  //...

  edit: (props) => {
    const {
      attributes: { story_id },
      setAttributes
    } = props;

    const stories = useSelect(
      select => select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords(
        'postType',
        'story',
        { id: story_id }
      ),
      [ story_id ]
    );

    // called, if a radiobutton gets selected
    const setStoryID = ( story_id ) => setAttributes( { story_id } );

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <StoriesListControl
          changeHandler={ setStoryID }
          story_id={ story_id }
          options={ stories }
        />
        <div className="story-container">
          <div id={ `story${ story_id }` } className="story-preview-container">
            <Story story_id={ story_id } />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Although this question is very old I will try this! Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Might be some bugs in there - I haven't tested it myself. But thought the question should get an answer/explanation in any scenario, even though it was likely you no longer required one :)